# Where was this character during the events of Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* movie,

> Lady Sif

was nowhere to be seen. Where was she? Did she survive Ragnarok?

Comment: Scheduling conflicts.

Comment: I’m not sure why the character’s name would be considered a spoiler. It should be safe to include her name in the title.

Comment: I gotta say, it's pretty clever of Jaimie Alexander to have a scheduling conflict with the movie that most likely would have killed her off. It is much easier to bring her back for future movies than the Warriors Three.

Comment: @JDoe Haha.. Nice one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[In universe](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1714409/what-happened-to-sif-after-thor-the-dark-world-according-to-kevin-feige), according to Marvel Studios President Kevin Feige:

> It's been in the works for many years, right, since we finished Dark
>   World. **What has Loki been doing on that throne in guise of Odin?** And
>   we always liked the idea that he was doing a good job! He was doing a
>   good, but shortsighted job. The trains were running on time, but he
>   wasn't paying attention to anything else going on in the universe or
>   in the realms. ... So that was always one idea. **And the idea that he
>   would have to get rid of Heimdall, because Heimdall can see
>   everything. That was an idea - and probably the Warriors Three, to
>   discount them...** which is probably an answer to a question I've been
>   asked a few times today: **Sif was probably banished. She's off
>   somewhere.**

[Out of universe](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/thor-ragnarok-jaimie-alexander-explains-lady-sif-mia-224123524.html):

> Yahoo Entertainment caught up with the actress, who currently stars in
>   the NBC show *Blindspot*, about why she didn’t return for the
>   blockbuster film.
>
> “I was asked, but **the timing of when they were going to shoot and when
>   *Blindspot* was gonna shoot — it was pretty much the same time,” she
>   told Yahoo on Friday. “So there was a conflict there.”**
>
> Alexander continued, “I was hoping for more of a notice from [the
>   studio] so I could make it work, but it was a short notice thing. **They
>   called and said, ‘Hey, by the way, would you come do this?’ I said
>   there is no way I can make that work that fast.”**
>
> Still, Alexander says she “tried,” noting, **“It couldn’t happen. They
>   were on a different continent!”** *Thor: Ragnarok* was filmed in
>   Australia.
>
> “So it was sad,” she admitted. “I was bummed about it.”

Comment: "I was bummed about it"
Probably for the best, given what happened to the others would probably have happened to her character too..